# Fetch image from folder and image data from database in php is not working

Tags: php, mysql, image

Table Name : image;

Field Name in database table : image_name;

Foldar Name : user_images

```
<?php
  $query= "select * from image where image_user_id ='".$_SESSION['userid']."'";
        echo $query;
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $imageURL = 'user_images/'.$row["image_name"];
                echo $imageURL;
                ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" data-fancybox="group" ></a>


            <?php }
        } ?>
```

Comment: You haven't execute query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you running the query on your database?

$query= "select * from image where image_user_id ='".$_SESSION['userid']."'"; //Here you are creating a string

echo $query; //Here you are printing the string to the view

I can not see anywhere that you are querying the database or calling a function to do it. That seems to be the main problem. Take a look at this link to see an example of setting up a connection and running a query on a DB http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers